# Why do these queries in Neo4j return different results?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am practicing on Neo4j movie database that come with it when you install Neo4j. For some reason, these two queries return different results:

```
match (keanu:Person {name: "Keanu Reeves"})-[:ACTED_IN]->()
<-[:ACTED_IN]-(actor), (actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other)  
where NOT ((keanu)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other)) and 
other <>keanu  return other.name, count(other) as count order by count DESC;
```

---

```
match (keanu:Person {name: "Keanu Reeves"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie)
<-[:ACTED_IN]-(actor), (actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other)  
where NOT ((keanu)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other)) and 
other <>keanu  return other.name, count(other) as count order by count DESC;
```

The only difference is that I specified 'movie' variable. I just want to look up the actors that have not played with Keanu, but have played with his co-stars most frequently. The results are the same, except when I specify a 'movie' variable a new actor is added to the top of the results (having most frequently acted with Keanu's co-stars). That actor does not show up at all in the first query results, but only in the second and tops the results.

Answer (score 1):

The first variant contains

```
where NOT ((keanu)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other))
```

The second one

```
where NOT ((keanu)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other))
```

So the first one filters out all paths where `keanu` acts together with `other` in **any** movie. The second one filters out all paths where `keanu` acts together with `other` in **this** movie.

Comment: But in the first match-line, 'movie' variable will contain all the movies that Keanu has ever played in, right? So when I use it in where-clause, there should not be any other movie Keanu has played in, except the ones contained in variable 'movie'? So why does it make no difference except adding one actor?